# Access to new class object's properties

Tags: c#

If I am creating a new class object and assigning its properties values like so:

```
foreach (var item in lstOfPersonnel)
{
    ClassNameVM personVM = new ClassNameVM ()
    {
        Name = item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName,
        TimeTotalPFID = lstSummaries.Where(x => x.PFID == item.ID).Sum(x => x.Time),
        TimeTotalPNFID = lstSummaries.Where(x => x.PNFID == item.ID).Sum(x => x.Time),
        TimeTotalVO = lstSummaries.Where(x => x.VO == item.ID).Sum(x => x.Time),
        TotalTime = // trying to do TimeTotalPFID + TimeTotalPNFID + TimeTotalVO.. but I can't access those properties.
    };

    newListPersonnel.Add(personVM);
}
```

How do I access the `TimeTotalPFID`, `TimeTotalPNFID`, `TimeTotalVO` properties within the object itself?

Comment: You can't if you do this way. You have to separate object creation and property assignment

Comment: @AkshayMahajan that's the way I was going to try next, but I figured I would ask to see if anyone has done this before

Comment: I tried that once but wasn't successful

Comment: Is `TotalTime` always the sum of those fields? If so why set it manually rather than just having the property be a getter that adds up those three values...

Comment: @Chris I didn't even think of that!  Please post this as an answer!

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid: Done! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case if you want the total time to just be the sum of other properties then don't work it out each time. This is error prone and doesn't respond correctly if the other properties change. Best in this case is to just have a property that only has a `get` which does the calculation for you...

```
public class ClassNameVM
{
    /*other properties as normal */
    public int TotalTime
    {
        get { return TimeTotalPFID + TimeTotalPNFID + TimeTotalVO; }
    }
}
```

Comment: also, different type of syntax for getters `public int TotalTime => TimeTotalPFID + TimeTotalPNFID + TimeTotalVO;`.  Thank you for the answer.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Ah yes. Very true. I'm a little bit old school (by which I mean our build server is still using an older version of c# and I don't get to use all these new syntaxes *sob*).

Answer (score 6):

You cannot access those properties as they technically don't exist within the scope of that anonymous object call.

Consider setting that property on the line below the declaration:

```
ClassNameVM personVM = new ClassNameVM ()
{
    Name = item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName,
    TimeTotalPFID = lstSummaries.Where(x => x.PFID == item.ID).Sum(x => x.Time),
    TimeTotalPNFID = lstSummaries.Where(x => x.PNFID == item.ID).Sum(x => x.Time),
    TimeTotalVO = lstSummaries.Where(x => x.VO == item.ID).Sum(x => x.Time),
};

// Set your properties here
personVM.TotalTime = personVm.TimeTotalPFID + personVM.TimeTotalPNFID + personVM.TimeTotalVO;
```

**Consider a Constructor**

Alternatively, you could define a constructor that would take in a parameter of your `item` type and use that:

```
public ClassNameVM(YourItemType item)
{
    Name = item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName;
    TimeTotalPFID = lstSummaries.Where(x => x.PFID == item.ID).Sum(x => x.Time);
    TimeTotalPNFID = lstSummaries.Where(x => x.PNFID == item.ID).Sum(x => x.Time);
    TimeTotalVO = lstSummaries.Where(x => x.VO == item.ID).Sum(x => x.Time);
    TotalTime = TimeTotalPFID + TimeTotalPNFID + TimeTotalVO;
}
```

Which would allow you to more easily use:

```
foreach (var item in lstOfPersonnel)
{
    newListPersonnel.Add(new ClassNameVM(item));
}
```

Comment: I do like the constructor idea, however I like Chris's answer in the comments!

Comment: His suggestion would work just fine. You didn't specify that you were never using those properties (or simply using them to just sum up the other values) so I assumed they were necessary. You could simply use `TimeTotalVO = lstSummaries.Where(x => x.VO == item.ID || x.PNFID == item.ID || x.PFID == item.ID).Sum(x => x.Time)`

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity.  I did give you an upvote though!

Comment: No problem. I included an example of how you could handle it using a single query in the previous comment.

Comment: Got it.  If Chris doesn't post his answer, I will accept yours

Comment: Was going to comment on sensible constructors myself. Too often I see every object having no constructor and then all the work being done in initializers like this. I'm a big fan of having relevant constructors whether that takes in `YourItemType` or the four values but they are there for a reason. :)

Answer (score 3):

Easiest solution would be:

```
ClassNameVM personVM = new ClassNameVM ()
        {
            Name = item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName,
            TimeTotalPFID = lstSummaries.Where(x => x.PFID == item.ID).Sum(x => x.Time),
            TimeTotalPNFID = lstSummaries.Where(x => x.PNFID == item.ID).Sum(x => x.Time),
            TimeTotalVO = lstSummaries.Where(x => x.VO == item.ID).Sum(x => x.Time),

        };
      personVM.TotalTime = personVM.TimeTotalPFID + personVM.TimeTotalPNFID + personVM.TimeTotalVO;
```